# no action when submit form

Tags: javascript, html

I am using form with HTML and JavaScript to check the input. I am doing it okay and if I enter a number I get message "Letters Only". But when I press the submit button, it doesn't give me the action page (w.php).

I want it so that when I press the login button take me to w.php page.

This is my code:

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="projectsite/include/validationEngine.jquery.css" />
<title>Projects Site</title>
</head>
<body background="se16.jpg">

<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<form id="my_form" method="post" action="w.php">
<center>
<br>
<h1> <p style="color:brown;">  Login Page </p> </h1> 

<hr color="brown"> <br> 
<caption><h1><p style="color:black;">please Enter Username & Password</p></h1><caption>
<table border="3">

<tr><td><h2><p style="color:black;">Username: </p></td><td><input type="text"     name="username" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetterSp]]" /></td><h2></tr>

<tr><td><h2><p style="color:black;">Password:</p> </td><td><input type="password" name="password" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetterPa]]" /></td></h2></tr>


<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Log in" /></td></tr>

</table>
</center>
</form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="projectsite/include/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
    <script src="projectsite/include/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
    <script>
        function ajaxValidationCallback(status, form, json, options) {

        if(status == true) {

                $(':input', '#my_form').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
                $("#message_sent").slideDown(400).delay(3000).slideUp(400);

          }
         }      
        $("#my_form").validationEngine({
            ajaxFormValidation : true,
            onAjaxFormComplete : ajaxValidationCallback,
            scroll : false
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That form should `POST` when you hit your submit button by the looks of it. Does it work when you turn javascript off in your web browser? Are there any javascript errors in your console when javascript is on?

Comment: I'm guessing you are making use of [this repo](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) for validation. In that case, where is the definition for `onlyLetterPa` coming from?

Comment: @tchow002 i am try it on chrome and inter explorer browser same problem. i am make Allow all sites to run JavaScript but same problem

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger  "onlyLetterPa": {
                    "regex": /^[a-zA-Z1-9\ \']+$/,
                    "alertText": "* Letters only"
                },

Comment: I believe the problem lies in the javascript. That's why I want you to try without javascript.

Comment: @tchow002 without javascript and check on inputs it is work good

Comment: @user3264926 Install [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) on your Firefox, it will show you why your page is being blocked from submitting if the error is due to javascript.

Answer (score 1):

based on the little I could research about the that Validation Engine, if you go for an AJAX validation the responsibility for submitting the form is on the callback.

link: https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/blob/master/demos/demoAjaxJAVA.html

```
// Called once the server replies to the ajax form validation request
function ajaxValidationCallback(status, form, json, options){
  if (console)
    console.log(status);

  if (status === true) {
    alert("the form is valid!");
    // uncomment these lines to submit the form to form.action
    // form.validationEngine('detach');
    // form.submit();
    // or you may use AJAX again to submit the data
  }
}
```